# Kill warp webserver on request in rust

Tags: multithreading, api, rust

I'm learning rust and for something that I want to do is kill, or shutdown, a webserver on `GET /`.

Is this something you can't do in with warp? Or is my implementation broken?

I've got the following code, but it just doesn't seem to want to respond to any HTTP requests.

```rust
pub async fn perform_oauth_flow(&self) {
        let (tx, rx) = channel::unbounded();

        let routes = warp::path::end().map(move || {
            println!("handling");
            tx.send("kill");
            Ok(warp::reply::with_status("OK", http::StatusCode::CREATED))
        });

        println!("Spawning server");
        let webserver_thread = thread::spawn(|| async {
            spawn(warp::serve(routes).bind(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3000)))
                .await
                .unwrap();
        });

        println!("waiting for result");
        let result = rx.recv().unwrap();
        println!("Got result");
        if result == "kill" {
            webserver_thread.join().unwrap().await;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using a string to control a thread is a bad idea. Use an enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rust
let webserver_thread = thread::spawn(|| async {
//                                      ^^^^^
```

Creating an `async` block is not going to execute the code inside; it is just creating a `Future` you need to `.await`. Your server never actually runs.

In general, using threads with async code is not going to work well. Better to use your runtime tasks, in case of `warp` it is [`tokio`](http://docs.rs/tokio), using [`tokio::spawn()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/fn.spawn.html):

```rust
let webserver_thread = tokio::spawn(async move {
    spawn(warp::serve(routes).bind(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3000)))
        .await
        .unwrap();
});

// ...

if result == "kill" {
    webserver_thread.await;
}
```

You may also find it necessary to use [tokio's async channels](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/mpsc/fn.unbounded_channel.html) instead of synchronous channels.

Comment: Thanks - this is different to what I know from TypeScript. Is Tokio generally a preferred framework for async programming?

I ended up using `webserver_thread.abort()` to kill the server, but this worked perfectly

Comment: @hjfitz Tokio is the mainly used one, although there are others. But in your case you have no choice - `warp` uses tokio (it uses `hyper` that is based on `tokio`), and so you cannot choose another runtime. And yes, async programming in Rust is very different than in js. js is like `spawn()`ing each and every future.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your code:

1. As pointed out by [@ChayimFriedman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72598494/5397009), you never start the server because your async block never runs.
2. Even if you replace the threads with Tokio tasks, you never tell the server to exit. You need to use [`bind_with_graceful_shutdown`](https://docs.rs/warp/latest/warp/struct.Server.html#method.bind_with_graceful_shutdown) so that you can notify the server to exit.

(Untested) complete example:

```
pub async fn perform_oauth_flow(&self) {
    let (tx, rx) = tokio::oneshot::channel();

    let routes = warp::path::end().map(move || {
        println!("handling");
        tx.send(());
        Ok(warp::reply::with_status("OK", http::StatusCode::CREATED))
    });

    println!("Spawning server");
    let server = warp::serve(routes)
               .bind_with_graceful_shutdown(
                   ([127, 0, 0, 1], 3000)),
                   async { rx.await.ok(); })
               .1;

    println!("waiting for result");
    server.await;
}
```

Comment: `bind_with_graceful_shutdown` returns a tuple, not a future. I think posting untested  examples here only causes further frustration, tbh, I think it's a good idea to at least see if they compile.

Comment: Note that `bind_with_graceful_shutdown` probably doesn't do what you think it does. It stops accepting new connections, and then waits until all existing connections got closed naturally.

Comment: @Finomnis yes, that is what I expected. This behaviour is required to ensure that the `warp::reply::with_status("OK", http::StatusCode::CREATED)` is sent to the client properly before the server shuts down.

Comment: This is the initial approach that I'd taken, tokio's channels don't implement Clone

Comment: @hjfitz why would you want to clone the channels?

Comment: @Jmb Might be a misinterpretation on my side, I'm new to the language. I thought that you'd need to clone them in order to move them in to a closure; I struggled to get this approach to work due to not being able to move the receiving channel.

Comment: @hjfitz you only need to clone them if you want to keep two copies (e.g. one that you move in the closure and another that you keep in the main function). Here there is no need for cloning since you only want to move it into the closure.

Comment: @jmb so digging a little more, `.move()` returns FnOnce and not Fn. I get from this that we'd need some copy of tx for each time the closure is called

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245582/discussion-between-jmb-and-hjfitz).

Comment: Like a bad novel, the "chat discussion" link above goes "Page Not Found".  :(  I was hoping to see the conclusion, result of this convo.  Am running into the same FnOnce (on the `tx.send()`) error.  Probably trying to do the same thing - running a web-based OAuth loop, and writing the returned code/token to a file, then shutting down the server for a CLI tool.  If you guys @Jmb and @hjfitz did resolve, would love an update.  :D

Comment: @KitPlummer there's actually only a single extra message in the chat: "_Nope, the single instance of `tx` is moved into the closure and then the same instance is reused each time the closure is called._"

Comment: Except that in this case the problem comes from using a `oneshot` channel, which as the name says can only be used once → hence the closure is an `FnOnce`. Using an `mpsc::channel` or `mpsc::unbounded_channel` should change the `FnOnce` into an `Fn`.